# How to grey out data placeholder on kendo multiselect dropdown

Tags: visual-studio, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

> I am having placeholder on kendo multiselect drop down and I wanted
>   that placeholder to be greyed out. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `placeholder` in kendo multiselect widget is treated as input text so you can do this:

```
div.k-multiselect input{
    color: #adadad;
}
```

Hope this works for you.